# SQL for creating a range

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have the below table with 2 columns

```
Dept   |   Term  

A      |    2010
A      |    2011
B      |    2012
C      |    2013
```

I want to create a maximum and minimum value columns such that the output should look as the table below. The minimum value can be obtained using the min() function and grouping by term column. The maximum value should be the minimum value from the next group.

```
Dept   |   min_Term  | max_term

A      |    2010     |  2012
B      |    2012     |  2013
C      |    2013     |  Null
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What happens if there's an `E` dept but no `D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `lead` function to get the mininmum term value from the next row.

```
with t1 as (
select dept, min(term) mnterm
from table
group by dept)
, t2 as (select dept, mnterm as min_term, lead(mnterm) over(order by dept) as max_term
         from t1)
select * from t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine aggregate and analytic functions in one shot like so:

```
select dept
     , min(term) min_term
     , lead(min(term)) over (order by dept) max_term
  from table
 group by dept;
```